# Expand a branch of Bootstrap tree on load

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have Bootstrap tree at http://www.bootply.com/wxu9KtYSQQ 
I collapse the whole tre using:

```
$('ul.tree').hide();
```

Is that possible to expand one branch of this tree while leaving all other branches collapsed on load? For example, expand BOOTSTRAP/BUTTONS but leave everything else collapsed. Thanks.

I tried putting an extra span class to BOOTSTRAP/BUTTONS but it doesn't work.

```
$('span.expand').show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding an `id` to the `ul` tag, and use that to load that tree at the start, like [this](http://www.bootply.com/gwh0eJDsQL)

```
<ul id="tree1" class="nav nav-list tree">
```

and

```
$('ul#tree1').toggle(200);
```

Comment: The children branch does not expand but I can work on that. many thanks.